# How to update simultaneously main window and popup (inside Struts2 app)?

Tags: jsp, redirect, struts2

Struts2. An action performs a query on DB and shows the result on a jsp.
The result is a list of records. Clicking on a row of this list it calls another action that calls a db query and shows on another window (popup) the detail of the record.
On this popup I can update the record and save changes on DB. In order to do it I call an action that, after performed DB changes, redirects on the second action (that which showing the detail popup) so I can see the record updated.
*The problem* is that, behind the popup, I see still (I have to do it!) the main window with the list but the list still shows, obviously, the old data of the updated record!

How can I update (refresh) at the same time  the popup and the list?

PS - constraints.
1-As I said, I have to display the pop-up and the list (it is a project requirement) so I can not upload the detail on the main window instead of the list.
2-The app must run on Chrome which, as noted, has a wretched usage  of "onbeforeunload" event, even if differently would not necessarily be a solution: the user might want to look at the main window not necessarily by closing the pop-up but just by moving it.

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: Use some javascript.

Comment: thanks to both of you. Aleksandr, could you be a little bit more verbose?
to give me a track, a tip, if not exactly an example? 
in which way I should use the script?

Comment: Roman you mean to say that it is not possible using redirect or chaining  or is not possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily accomplish this with a little bit of jQuery and AJAX.

- Select the row in question, sending an AJAX request to a Struts2 action that responds with an HTML response that represents a partial page that you load into a div.    This response fragment contains a jQuery modal dialog box that opens upon load.
- Edit the record in the modal box.
- Clicking the save button submits the form using AJAX to another Struts2 action.  This action can either return JSON or another partial HTML response.  I often find it easier to work with partial HTML fragments.
- On error, the partial HTML fragment contains the form with the various field errors indicated so that the user can make modifications.
- On success, the partial HTML fragment contains a small javascript fragment that raises an event that the original table responds to to reload it's data, perhaps via AJAX from the server.  Additionally, the javascript fragment instructs the opened dialog window to close and perhaps remove itself from the DOM.

So yes, it is doable but does require Javascript, as indicated in a comment.

Comment: Naros hello, sorry for the late response but I temporarily shelved the trouble. I will try to follow your advice, adjusting it to my needs: from the application someone decided to eliminate all ajax standard  functions (Dojo, JQuery - excluding DateTimePicker) and replace them with source code so I will try to follow your track trying to write something similar in plain JavaScript. Thanx